# Integral of a convination of nested exponentials.

Tags: integration, exponentiation

I would like to calculate the following integral

$$  \displaystyle\int_0^{T} e^{-s\left[t+\frac{1}{\mu}(e^{-\mu r }- e^{-\mu(r-t)})\right]} dt$$

where $s,\mu, r$ are constant values.

What I have done:

after some algebra I got that this integral is equivalent to

$$ c\displaystyle\int_0^{T} e^{-st} e^{-c e^{\mu t}}dt $$

where $c = e^{-\frac{s}{\mu} e^{-\mu r}} $.

Now, from my understanding this integral is not possible to solve it analytically, but I am not 100% sure since I do not know how to prove that.

Any insights are appreciated.